# Generics Solution for ToViewModel type function (MVVM)

Tags: c#, mvvm

How can I use C# generics to avoid having to create an extension function like so for each and every auto-generated class (Linq to SQL DBML)?

```
static public CharacterViewModel ToViewModel(this Character c)
{
    return new CharacterViewModel(c);
}
```

Having a function like this provides a fairly clean way of selecting a set of items from the DB as their corresponding ViewModel, like so:

```
var characters = new ObservableCollection<CharacterViewModel>(from p in DB.Characters
                                                              select p.ToViewModel());
```

I'd like to see something like:

```
static public T ToViewModel<T,K>(K dbmlClass)
{
     return new T(dbmlClass);
}
```

But I have a feeling this will involve Reflection-style object generation and I don't know how efficient that would be (or how to accomplish it).

By the way, I did previously investigate operator overloading the assignment ('=') as a possible solution, which could provide implicit casting, but I believe this would require overloading the = in the auto-generated class which I am not able to do.

### Update

Thanks all, for the answers. I think I have a few avenues to check out now. To provide a bit more context, as some mentioned it wasn't clear. All of my ViewModels are derived from the following:

```
public class BaseDO<T>: BaseDO
{
    public BaseDO(T model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public T Model { get; set; }
}

abstract public class BaseDO: INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDeleted
{

    #region Standard INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (o, e) => { };
    #endregion


    public event EventHandler OnEntityDeleted = (o, e) => { };

    public void NotifyEntityDeleted()
    {
        OnEntityDeleted(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public interface INotifyDeleted
{
    event EventHandler OnEntityDeleted;
    void NotifyEntityDeleted();
}
```

Comment: the main issue with this as a concept is that generics only supports parameterless constructors, so you can't just create the view model,

Comment: if you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx , you will see you can use the implicit operator to tell a View model how to build itself from the model class so no changes needed to the model

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library such as [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). With this you have 1 place where you setup the configuration of how objects are mapped. You can then have:

```
public static T ToViewModel<T,K>(K dbmlClass) 
{
    return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T>(dbmlClass); 
}


// Register mappings
public static void ConfigureMappings()
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Character, CharacterViewModel>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your question whether you want to generate the view model classes automatically or whether you've already written them and each one accepts the model as a constructor parameter. If the former then I personally add INPC to the model classes using either Castle Proxy or Frody. If the latter then I believe this is what you're after:

```
public static class Helper
{
    static public T ToViewModel<T>(this object dbmlClass)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), dbmlClass);
    }
}
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
var model = new Model();
var view_model = model.ToViewModel<ViewModel>();
```